# SpotLight not working in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a ribbon that displays a few thumbnails. Just to give a background, the thumbnail images are painted on a canvas, which is then added to Texture.

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture(textureCanvas);
```

The mesh is created as follows

```
    loader.load('mesh_blender.js', function(geom) {
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xffffffff,
        opacity: 0.7,
        overdraw: 0.21,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent: true,
        //shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        map: texture
      }));
```

Everything till here is fine. The ribbon is created as follows

[image]

I have no complaints with this. But I need this additional effect you see in the image below. As it can be seen, the thumbnail that is in the centre (focus) needs to have a darker effect to show it is being highlighted/selectable. All the remaining thumbnails have a transparent effect depicting they are not selectable.

[image]

I am trying to wrap my head around this using Lights in Threejs but not very successful. I thought of using an AmbientLight to throw light on the entire ribbon and then an additional SpotLight only on the centre image (with a darker color maybe) to achieve the desired effect. But that didn't work. I have got something like this

[image]

But the centre focused image has no effect. As you can see in the image, I have used a helper to show the Light direction but I can't really see any light on the image. This is the code I use to develop that SpotLight

```
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffeedd );
spotLight.position.set( 0, -50, 50 );
spotLight.castShadow = true;
    //spotLight.penumbra = 0.2;
spotLight.decay = 2;
spotLight.distance = 300;
spotLight.angle = 0.5;
var helper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( spotLight, 2.5 );
scene.add(helper);

scene.add( spotLight );
```

I am very new to Threejs and 3d graphics. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.I am open to any other suggestion as well, if Lights are not to be used to achieve the end result.

Comment: An alternative approch to the answer already given may be to create your own ShaderMaterial

Answer (score 0):

You have given the opacity of the material as 0.7 so adding another light will not exactly give you the expected result. I would suggest using a raycaster to identify the object in the center and making the opacity of that object as 1 and the rest as 0.7.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
```

use this to get the objects that are intersecting in an array. And in the renderer function set the opacity of the first element in the array that is the object in the middle to 1. This only works if the thumbnails are all separate objects.

```
//set as the center of you vision
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
mouse.x = 0;
mouse.y = 0;

function highlightObject() {

// update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position    
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );   

// calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

//sets the object in the center opacity = 0.2
if(intersects.length > 0) {
    intersects[0].object.material.opacity = 0.2;
}

//sets the opacity of the rest of the objects in scene to opacity = 1.0
for (var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var obj = scene.children[i];
    obj.material.opacity = 1.0;

}
 }
```

Comment: I did get the interesting objects array using raycaster. But the problem is when I try to change the opacity of the object at the 0th position, the opacity of the entire ribbon changes. I only want to change the opacity of the facing/middle thumbnail.

Comment: I do not quite understand when you separate objects. Each thumbnail is a different image that is drawn on canvas using ctx.drawImage()

Comment: Also, if we take the Light approach and change the opacity from 0.7 to 1 and use the AmbientLight and SpotLight in combination, it still does not work.

Comment: And if I somehow change the opacity using raycaster, when the ribbon moves, I need to change back the opacity of the previous thumbnail and also change the opacity for the new facing thumbnail.. Wouldn't that be expensive?

Comment: That is because when you take the object in the zeroth position it is the whole ribbon and not the image alone ...make the images you need into separate objects so that you get that object instead of the whole ribbon

Comment: You can have the same functionality as a ribbon by making them into separate objects and placing them into an array and on swipe rotate every model in that array with axis at the origin or ..simply roaring the camera and adding the raycaster light to the camera so that the light is always where the camera is pointing towards the centre

Comment: Can you give code snippets for explanation please? I think this 3D thing is too difficult for me to understand only through comments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: from your description i presume the ribbon is the object and the thumbnails are textures in the object. If you use raycaster in such a situation it returns the first intersecting object that is the ribbon. if you have separate objects for the thumbnails then you can get the object in the center. It is rather expensive but it will give you your desired result

Comment: Thanks for this bit of the code. What I was actually asking for was the code for creating separate objects. Currently, what I have  done is create a canvas, then use drawImage to draw each individual image and then finally put the canvas into Texture. This Texture is then provided as map to the LambertMeshMaterial.

Comment: your mesh_blender.js is an object mesh file. similarly you need to make each thumbnail as a plane/object and instead of using a canvas, add texture for each object as it is. Add the objects into the scene

Comment: Wouldn't that be very expensive rendering?

Comment: as i mentioned earlier it would be expensive but it would get the job done ...opacity is a property of the mesh and not the image. So getting your desired result otherwise in my understanding is not likely

Comment: Thanks for getting back to all queries. I really appreciate. The point being, in some cases I can have up to 30 images which I believe will be very expensive for rendering.  Don't you think light approach will be easier? Though I am not able to do it now, but what if I am able to have a SpotLight focus at the centre and which image comes there will be darker. And I use an AmbientLight to glow all other images? But I am not able to get this done.

Comment: This is my camera angle now camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1024/768, 1, 3000); camera.position.set(0, 400, 1000); camera.rotation.set(-Math.PI/16, 0, 0); I am not sure how to use Light and position it.. Please help

Comment: Your idea of using a spotlight and an ambient light works but ..you cant control the opacity with a light source. Make the opacity of the object to 1.0 and then try using the above mentioned idea. Use a helper to check your spotlight direction

Comment: I have already tried doing that. But doesn't work. I have used the helper as you can see in the image above where I am trying to use SpotLight on the centre image. Does it have anything to do with the positioning? I don't really want to control the opacity. I somehow want to show that the centre image is focused/selectable.